# MySQL query - Case and Group By Select

Tags: mysql, sql

My table data is below

```
products_name      |   display_product
---------------------------------------    
Product 1          |        True
Product 1          |        False
Product 13         |        True
Product 14         |        False
```

What I want is to get value "0" if any of the product `display_product` column have a false value, "1" otherwise.

Comment: `MAX(product_name)` with `group by product name` ? what exactly you are trying provide some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product_name, 
       sum(display_products = 'false') > 0 as has_false
from your_table
group by product_name
```